# Always getting value of first input element. Trouble with JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

$divCreator below is a variable. It can take value from 1 to 10. I am using the below html inside a while loop in php. Now what i want to do is that i want to pass two variables to a php script. One is quesID and the other is testID. I already have the value of testID. But the problem occurs with the quesID. I am always getting the quesID value as 1. Which is the value from the first form built from the while loop.
The HTML code is :

```
<form id="form_create_ques" action="" method="get">
    <div class="grid-6 grid grey">
        <input id="quesid_form" name="quesID" type="text" value="<?php echo $divCreator;  ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="button_create_ques" value="<?php echo $divCreator; ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery code : (My Jquery is pretty weak so i need some help).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function (){
  $(".button_create_ques").click(function(){
    var form_data = $("#form_create_ques").serialize(); //Always returns quesID=1
    alert(form_data);
    $.ajax({
    url: "create_ques.php?testID=<?php echo $_GET['testID']; ?>",
    type: 'GET',
    data: form_data,
    success: function() 
            {
             //Do something..
            }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
```

If you have any better or alternate solution, then please do explain. I would really appreciate that. Sorry, i am still learning Jquery.

Comment: If you're outputing that HTML in a loop, you have multiple elements with the same ID. That isn't allowed, IDs have to be unique.

Comment: So how about adding somthing like <form id="form_create_ques<?php echo $divCreator; ?>"></form> ? 
But then how would i pass this value to the jquery function. How will i tell it which unique id it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` values must be unique within a document.  Because your forms all have the same `id`, using a selector such as `$("#form_create_ques")` will always return the first occurrence of this `id`.

You can remove the `id` entirely and use this to get the `form` based on the button:

```
var form_data = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
```

Comment: Aww great! This is it! Thanks a lot. I will accept the answer. It says i cannot accept the answer for the next 7 minutes. I will do it as soon as i can. 
Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 possible ways:

1: Add new `hidden` field to form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="quesID" value="<?php echo addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['testID'])); ?>" />
```

2: remove `data: form_data,` and modify:

```
url: "create_ques.php?testID=<?php echo $_GET['testID']; ?>&" + form_data,
```

Answer (score 1):

Since IDs have to be unique, you can't give all your forms the same ID. So leave out the ID.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <div class="grid-6 grid grey">
        <input id="quesid_form" name="quesID" type="text" value="<?php echo $divCreator;  ?>" />
        <input type="submit" class="button_create_ques" value="<?php echo $divCreator; ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

You should then use DOM traversal functions in the jQuery to find the form corresponding to the button that was clicked:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
  $(".button_create_ques").click(function(){
    var form_data = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
    alert(form_data);
    $.ajax({
    url: "create_ques.php?testID=<?php echo $_GET['testID']; ?>",
    type: 'GET',
    data: form_data,
    success: function() 
            {
             //Do something..
            }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
```